# Why won't this loop normalize my Vector2 list?

Tags: c#, xna, foreach

See the following code:

```
    List<Vector2> axes = new List<Vector2>();
    axes.Add(TopRight() - TopLeft());
    axes.Add(BottomLeft() - TopLeft());
    axes.Add(otherRectangle.TopRight() - otherRectangle.TopLeft());
    axes.Add(otherRectangle.BottomLeft() - otherRectangle.TopLeft());
    // Try normalizing vectors?
    foreach (Vector2 axis in axes)
    {
        axis.Normalize();
    }
```

the `Vector2.Normalize()` method is a void method that normalizes the vector it's called on. Yet for some reason when I do this loop it doesn't normalize the vectors. Am I just unable to modify a list this way?

**Some oddities:**

- Iterating with a for loop, i.e. `axis[i].Normalize()` doesn't work.
- Iterating with the built-in `List<T>.ForEach` iterator does not work.
- Creating a normalizing the vector before adding it to the list rather than iterating over the list *does* work.

Why does iteration not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `foreach` loop creates a local copy of the sequence element. You only normalize the copy.

You will need to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<axes.Count; i++)
    axes[i] = Vector2.Normalize(axes[i]);
```

This unintuitive behavior demonstrates, once again, why instance methods that mutate a struct are a bad idea.

Comment: This is what I was talking about when I mentioned iterating with a for loop in my original post. However it also doesn't work when I use a C# List<T>.ForEach iterator so I'm starting to think there might be something somewhere else in my code that's causing problems... Also normalize is a void method.

Comment: The explanation is sound but your code makes no sense – [`Normalize` isn’t a static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.normalize.aspx). Just use OP’s approach, minus the `foreach`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The overload I chose is static and returns the normalized value. `public static Vector2 Normalize(Vector2 value)`

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sure enough I didn't realize that there was a static normalize method, however this use is incredibly unintuitive. I switched to this method.

Answer (score 3):

As CodesInChaos said, `Vector2.Normalize` is a badly designed method (the reason for this decision is probably out of performance considerations, but that doesn’t help us here).

As a consequence, it *mutates* the object it works on. However, that object is a *copy* of the original object in a `foreach` look. So your code only mutates objects, not those in the actual list.

The only workaround is to use an indexed `for` loop over the items in the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < axes.Count; i++) {
    Vector2 copy = axes[i];
    copy.Normalize();
    axes[i] = copy;
}
```

Here, we modify a copy, but we copy it back inside the actual vector afterwards. Note that we **cannot** simply modify `axes[i]` by writing `axes[i].Normalize()` – this is arguably (and in my opinion) *another* design flaw in .NET. The reason is that the `axes[i]` operation is a property access (accessing the `this[]` property) which, once again, returns a *copy* of the original object.

Comment: This did the trick and I'm going to accept it as it makes sense to me regarding the implementation of the Normalize method.

Comment: The manual copy is much uglier than using `axes[i]=Vector2.Normalize(axes[i])`.

Answer (score 0):

**MORE EDITS:**
try first normalize vectors, and then add them to list...

```
List<Vector2> axes = new List<Vector2>();

Vector2 tempTopRightTopLeftVector = TopRight() - TopLeft();
tempTopRightTopLeftVector.Normalize();
axes.Add(tempTopRightTopLeftVector);

Vector2 tempBottomLeftTopRightVector = BottomLeft() - TopLeft();
tempBottomLeftTopRightVector.Normalize();
axes.Add(tempBottomLeftTopRightVector);

// and so on for other vectors...
```

**MORE EDITS:**

Try to use another type of collection. Array for example:

```
Vector2[] axes = new Vector2[] {
   TopRight() - TopLeft(),
   BottomLeft() - TopLeft(),
   otherRectangle.TopRight() - otherRectangle.TopLeft(),
   otherRectangle.BottomLeft() - otherRectangle.TopLeft()
}
for(int i=0; i<axes.Length; i++)
{
   axes[i].Normalize();
}
```

Comment: Does not compile, the sig of this overload is `public void Normalize()`. Your code is assuming that `Vector2` works as it should, and not as it actually does.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Even if `Normalize` worked as it should this code wouldn’t work.

Comment: This DOES work for some reason. My biggest issue is with why it *doesn't* work through iteration.

Comment: @KonradRudolph When I commented he had posted different code. @ssb The new code works because it's an array, where access through an index doesn't cause a copy. When indexing into a `List<T>` or using `foreach` you work on a copy.